# Background picture size

Tags: html, css, background

I have this picture, but I want to fit my screen. It's longer than my screen. If I put background-size: cover, it fit the screen but it's half in width. But if I don't put that, it's half of the screen in height.

This is my CSS code.

```
min-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always weird to use % in height, because height is scrollable and therefore infinite.

Instead you could try using **vh** and **vw** (view height/view width)

These control the current size of the open window.

It may mess with the ratio of your photo if you change both, so I would try

**width: auto;
height: 100vh;**

Comment: Yeah,  I use too vh and vw, but I follow some example from the internet, and forgot to change. Also I tried your suggestion but the background image, don't go 100vh(It don't stretch to bottom of my screen), it goes nearly half my screen.

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code? Is it perhaps inside of another div that isn't stretching the entire height? I'd have to see the whole document and css to see why it isn't stretching all the way. Sometimes if you do the background on the body itself it doesn't fit the whole screen because the body height isn't taking up the whole screen. You may have to keep playing around and adding height to the parent containers